# User wise redirect after Login Using Laratrust

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in Laravel. I am trying laratrust for role wise authentication. Can any one tell me, how to redirect user according to their role after login.
I.E:
Admin User
Redirect to : /admin

Employee User
Redirect to: /employee

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What version of Laravel are you using? are you using the built in auth routes?

Comment: show something that u tried, also please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What you have done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to overwrite the entire login logic, if you source dive into the Framework you'll see that Laravel uses the following to determine the redirect path after the login.

```
    /**
     * Get the post register / login redirect path.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function redirectPath()
    {
        if (method_exists($this, 'redirectTo')) {
            return $this->redirectTo();
        }
        return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
    }
```

So all you need to do is add a `redirectTo()` method to your `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php` and put your custom logic in that method where you should be able to use `$this->guard()->user()` to get the authenticated user and generate the custom logic that you need to implement.

```
    /**
     * Get the post register / login redirect path.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function redirectTo()
    {
        if ($this->guard()->user()->hasRole('admin')) {
            return '/admin';
        }

        return '/employee';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used something like this in laravel 5.4.35
I have overwrite laravel login function.
This is some code segment of my Auth/LoginController.php

But you have to do something, before asking for the the whole answer.
Find about how to overwrite Laravel default login function.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
class LoginController extends Controller
{


public function login(Request $request)
    {
        //validate the form data
        $this->validate($request,[
                'email'=> 'required|email',
                'password'=> 'required|min:8|max:16'
        ]);


        if($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)){
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }
        if (Auth::validate(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password])){
            $user = Auth::getLastAttempted();           
                if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password],$request->remember)){

                    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
                    $role="";//yo have to catch user roles acording to your system.
                    if($role==1){// then use the conditional logic to redirect.
                        return redirect('/admin');
                    }elseif($role==2){
                        return redirect('/employee');
                    }

                }
                        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
                return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email','remember'))->withErrors([
                        'err' => 'Matching credential not found'
                ]);

        }
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email','remember'))->withErrors([
                'err' => 'Matching credential not found'
        ]);

    }

}
```